# How to synchronize changes in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a view with a tableviewer and another one with a text widget. When I select something in table viewer the text selected is shown in the text widget and I can edit that text. How can I update the table viewer with the text from the text widget while editing?

Comment: I am sure tableViewer will allow you to add onSelect event handler. Register your event handler and inspect the event and get the text of the tree.. set it to textbox

Comment: I can set the text to the textbox. But after that if I change the text in the textbox, I need to update the text in the table to show the one from the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to listen to `SWT.Verify` in the `Text` and update the `TableViewer` data accordingly:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    text.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            String oldString = text.getText();
            String newString = oldString.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + oldString.substring(e.end);

            /* SET STRING TO TABLEVIEWER DATA HERE */

            System.out.println(newString);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you just want to update the table when the user is done changing the text, listen for `SWT.FocusOut` on the `Text` instead.